# Let $G$ act on the vertices of the regular pentagon, show this gives rise to a homomorphism from $G$ to $S_5$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Let $G=D_{10}$, the dihedral group of order 10. Show how the actions of G on the vertices of the regular pentagon give rise to a homomorphism $\phi: G \rightarrow S_5$.

My question is this. I think that I am struggling with the 'gives rise part'. I was thinking of using the orbit stabiliser theorem to show that that $\langle a, b\rangle$ where $a=(1,2,3,4,5)$ and $b = (2,3)(4,5)$ generate the entire group $S_5$, but I am not even sure that this is the case. My question is this

Thank you so much!

Comment: Note a homomorphism does not have to be surjective. Indeed, it can't be here since $|D_{10}|=10$ and $|S_5|=5!=120$.

Comment: "Gives rise" is just a figure of speech meaning "defines".

Comment: This is ultimately showing that identifying the action of $D_{10}$ on the vertices labeled 1 to 5 provides a natural homomorphism into $S_5,$ so you can view a subgroup of the permutations on 1 to 5 as the group of symmetries of a Pentagon. As @zipirovich said the "gives rise" part just indicates that this homomorphism is, in a way, naturally induced by a change of labeling of vertices.

Answer (score 0):

A group action of any group $G$ on a set $X$ is actually a homomorphism $G \to \mathrm{Sym}(X)$, where $\mathrm{Sym}(X)$ denotes the group of all bijections $X \to X$, with group multiplication given by function composition. This is easily checked from the definitions. If $X = \{1, \cdots, n\}$, then $\mathrm{Sym}(X) = S_n$, so you should already have your homomorphism.

Comment: but how would we check that products go to products in this case?

Comment: The axioms of a group action include that $g \cdot (h \cdot x) = gh \cdot x$, which looks like the right thing to use.